# Google Maps Kml layer Zoom

Tags: google-maps, zooming, kml

I am using this initialization of my map. I would like my map to come into my "map-container" zoomed in more (maybe 16 zoom). Where can I add this zoom parameter? Is this possible?

```
function initialize() {
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-container'), {

}),

myMapsId = 'zpR-Rs8swcrY.kxIipB_folRg&usp';
  new google.maps
    .KmlLayer({
      map: map,
      url: 'https://www.google.com/maps/d/kml?mid=' + myMapsId
    });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 0):

You add the zoom parameter (and the center parameter, you need both) in the [MapOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MapOptions).

In order to prevent the KmlLayer from zooming and centering the map on the KML content, you need to set the [preserveViewport option of the KmlLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#KmlLayerOptions) to true.

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-container'), {
      zoom: 16,
      center: {
        lat: 56.620599,
        lng: -6.076408
      }

    }),

    myMapsId = 'zpR-Rs8swcrY.kxIipB_folRg&usp';
  new google.maps
    .KmlLayer({
      map: map,
      url: 'https://www.google.com/maps/d/kml?mid=' + myMapsId,
      preserveViewport: true
    });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map-container" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```